# How do I disable PHP's file read/write buffers?

Tags: php

If I write a line to a file, then flush the buffer, then write a second line, then seek to the beginning and read the file -- it only reads the first line. It's like it doesn't think I've written the second line.

Code to reproduce:

```
$fh = fopen('filename.dat', 'r+');
stream_set_write_buffer($fh, 0);
stream_set_read_buffer($fh, 0);
fwrite($fh, "Testing 123.\n");
fflush($fh);
fwrite($fh, "Testing 456.\n");
fflush($fh);
fseek($fh, 0);
echo fgets($fh, 26);
fclose($fh);
```

That will output...

```
"Testing 123.\n"
```

instead of

```
"Testing 123.\nTesting 456.\n".
```

I'm using PHP 5.4.16.

Help! This is driving me mad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[fgets()](http://docs.php.net/fgets) reads one line, i.e. if it encounters a linebreak/carriage-return character it stops reading.

You might be interested in http://docs.php.net/fread

Comment: DOH! I can't believe I missed that. Thanks!